# Stacked bar plot - percentage

Tags: pandas, stacked-chart

I want to represent this information in a stacked bar plot in percentage
On the x axis I want the age groups and on the y axis and the values that represent percentage of Gender in each age group
Age is represented by bins in the dataset
I have this so far
[image]

This is my code:

```
c = ds.groupby(['Age','Gender'])['Gender'].count()

d=(((c /c.groupby(level=0).sum())*100).round()).astype('int64')

d
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a test data frame:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({'Gender': ['F','M','F','F','F','M','M','M','F','F','M','F','F','M','M','M','M','F','F','M','M','M'], 'Age': [17,10,20,51,53,15,50,60,43,28,35,67,33,17,20,40,43,47,48,51,53,54]})
```

You can use [pandas.cut](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) function to segment the age into proper intervals:

```
bins = pd.IntervalIndex.from_tuples([(0,17),(17,25),(25,35),(35,46),(46,50),(50,55), (55,np.inf)])
df['Age_interval'] = pd.cut(df['Age'], bins=bins)
df = df.groupby(['Age_interval', 'Gender']).size().unstack().fillna(0)

df['F'] = df['F']/sum(df['F']+df['M'])*100

df['M'] = df['M']/sum(df['M']+df['F'])*100

df['Age'] = ['0-17', '18-25','26-35', '36-45', '46-50', '51-55', '55-']

df.plot(kind='bar', x='Age', title = 'Gender distribution in Age groups', rot=0,figsize=(10,5), color=['turquoise','brown'], stacked=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I thought that each bar should sum to 100%. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: @LenaMeer I am sorry, there was a mistake. I should have divided each gender by the number of all people in the data frame regardless of their sex. I have edited the answer. Now the bars sum up to 100%